# Gamma of a mixture of multiple gases

Tags: thermodynamics

Gamma is defined as $$\frac{C_p}{C_v}$$

Now say you have a mixture of gases eg: 1 mol of monoatomic gas and 2 moles of diatomic gas, then how would I find the value of gamma of this new mixture of gases?

Comment: What are your thoughts on this?  How is Cp of an ideal gas mixture related to the Cp's of the individual components?  What is the heat of mixing of ideal gases?

Comment: Oh so you're saying to use energy conservation whilst writing energy of gas as $U = n C_v \Delta T?$

Comment: No. You need to understand and quantify the mixture rules for ideal gases.  Each gas species behaves as if the other gas species are not present.

Comment: Sure, yeah the pressures add up , the volumes add up and the temperature has a funky relation. How do I apply this to find gamma?

Comment: Have this same question.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Once the gases are mixed and at same temperature,

$$ (n_1 + n_2) \overline{C_v} T = n_1 C_{v_1} T + n_2 C_{v_2} T$$

Cancelling temperatures,

$$(n_1+n_2)\bar{C_v}=n_1C_{v1}+n_2C_{v2}$$ where $\bar{C_v}$ is the molar average heat capacity at constant volume of the mixture.  So $$\bar{C_v}=x_1C_{v1}+x_2C_{v2}$$and $$\bar{C_p}=x_1C_{v1}+x_2C_{v2}+R$$So, for the mixture, $$\gamma=\frac{\bar{C_p}}{\bar{C_v}}=1+\frac{R}{x_1C_{v1}+x_2C_{v2}}$$or
$$\gamma=1+\frac{1}{\frac{x_1}{(\gamma_1-1)}+\frac{x_2}{(\gamma_2-1)}}$$
I'm sure that this can be simplified some more, but I'll leave that up to you.

Comment: Question: How did you know you could directly add C_vs scaled by molar oefficent ?

Comment: Because I know that the heat of mixing of ideal gases is zero.

Comment: That's what I said in the comment by applying energy conversation bruh

Comment: I came back to this question but I still can't understand how you achieved the premise. The only way that equation can be stated (afaik) is if gases are mixed at same temperature, did you assume this?

Comment: @ Buraian Of course.  In a gas mixture/solution, how can they not be at the same temperature.  And, of course, for ideal gasses, the enthalpy and internal energy changes on mixing are zero.  So the partial molar internal energies and enthalpies of the individual components in the mixture are the same as for the pure gases at the same temperature.

Comment: I have put that point in your answer, in case anyone else comes and checks this in the future

Comment: Thank you dear Chet Miller, Will this hold if gases are not ideal?

Comment: @YasirSadiq  No, unfortunately, it will not hold if the gases are not ideal (except, of course, in the limit of low pressures).